# peewee rbac tables many to many query

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, peewee, rbac

Question involves a rbac five tables design namely User, UserRole, Role, RolePermission, Permission (Mysql).
I would like to know how to query users who have (all) the specified permissions using peewee.

Right now I'm simply doing multiple queries and get their intersection:

```
u1 = User.select().join(UserRole).join(Role).join(RolePermission).join(Permission).where(
    Permission.permission_type == 1)
u2 = User.select().join(UserRole).join(Role).join(RolePermission).join(Permission).where(
    Permission.permission_type == 2)
u3 = User.select().join(UserRole).join(Role).join(RolePermission).join(Permission).where(
    Permission.permission_type == 3)
result = set(u1).intersection(set(u2).intersection(set(u3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join for where the permssion-type is in a given list, and then aggregate the count of matches using a GROUP BY, then filter for all matches with HAVING.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Could you please provide an example using peewee?